# Итоговый размер aes

Tags: c#, .net, криптография, aes

Необходимо узнать размер выходных данных зашифрованных с помощью aes.

В интернете нашел формулу

```
int endSize = (startSize / 16) * 16 + (startSize%16 == 0 ? 0 : 16)
```

Логика понятна - если размер не влезает кратно в блоки aes (которые 16 байт), то выравниваем до кратного.
Однако оказалось, что более правильная формула

```
int endSize = (startSize / 16) * 16 + 16
```

Тестовый пример:

```
var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("12345", iv);
var aes = new AesManaged();
aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
var buffer = new byte[4096];
using (var instream=File.OpenRead("z:/in.txt"))
{
      using (var crptoStream=new CryptoStream(instream,
           aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
      {
           using (var outstream = File.OpenWrite("z:/out.bin"))
           {
               do
               {
                    var count = crptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if(count==0)break;
                    outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                } while (true);
            }
      }
}
```

Для проверки взял файл 15 байт - на выходе ожидаемые 16 байт.
Добавил байт. 16 байт на входе - на выходе 32.

Почему так получается? Данных хватает и Padding по идее не должен вмешиваться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выравнивание по PKCS#7 описано в [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.3).

> For such algorithms, the method shall be to pad the input at the
> trailing end with k - (l mod k) octets all having value k - (l mod k),
> where l is the length of the input.

Формула `k - (l mod k)` (где l - длина входных данных, k - размер блока) в случае входных данных кратных 16 будет равен 16, то есть еще 16 байт будут записаны в виде открытого текста равного 16.
Таким образом, выравнивания будут выглядеть так:

```
                 01 -- if lth mod k = k-1
              02 02 -- if lth mod k = k-2
                  .
                  .
                  .
        k k ... k k -- if lth mod k = 0
```

**Важно:** Этот метод заполнения хорош тогда и только тогда, когда k меньше 256.

А формула для вычисления конечного размера:

```
int endSize = startSize + (k - (startSize % k)); //, где k - размер блока
```

Comment: То есть алгоритм вместо определения "сколько байт нужно дополнить до размера блока и нужны ли они вообще" просто всегда считает по формуле k - (l mod k)?

Comment: @vitidev  верно, и соответствующе заполняет их

Comment: Последний вопрос. Я заметил что PaddingMode.Zeros не подчиняется этому правилу и ведет себя по умному. Почему так?

Comment: @vitidev потомучто это другой метод заполнения, который состоит в добавление до размера блока нулевыми байтами. **НО** дополнение нулями может быть необратимо, если оригинальное сообщение заканчивалось одним или несколькими нулевыми байтами, что делает невозможным отличить байты открытого текста от байтов заполнения.

Comment: В формуле точно нет ошибки? Больше похоже, что должно быть int endSize = startSize  + (k - (startSize % k));

Comment: @vitidev верно, поправил, дурацкий копипаст =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64014/discussion-between-lex-hobbit-and-vitidev).

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ты используешь стандартный [`Padding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) - PKCS7. Как минимум 1 байт используется для хранения количества добавленных байт.

Comment: Откуда такая информация? На msdn написано "Строка заполнения PKCS #7 состоит из последовательности байтов, каждый из которых равен общему числу добавленных байтов заполнения.".

Comment: @vitidev PKCS#7 описан в  [RFC5652] (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3), там написано For such algorithms, the method shall be to pad the input at the trailing end with k - (l mod k) octets all having value k - (l mod k), where l is the length of the input.